# Killing infinite ffmpeg on the command line from an application

Tags: qt, ffmpeg

I am using

```
ffmpeg.exe -f dshow -i audio=virtual-audio-capturer -q 4 -y -tune zerolatency outfile.mp3
```

to grap sound from speakers. This command runs infinitely. I have to use

```
Process->kill();
```

command to stop execution of this command in my application.

I want to know if it is safe to kill it the way I am killing, or is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Qt documentation states](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#kill), using the function kill will terminate the process immediately.

So, depending on what you count as 'safe' this may or may not be ok for you. If ffmpeg is in the middle of processing data, or saving to file, calling this will stop it from finishing its task.

You could ask the process politely to stop, by [sending it a signal](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/basics-daemons.html) such as kill(pid, SIGABRT), if you're using Linux or OSX. Windows will likely have an [equivalent method](https://serverfault.com/questions/151196/how-is-the-windows-kill-process-works).